# Python. Поиск значений из словаря в текстовых файлах

Tags: python, файлы, циклы, словари

1.Есть словарь:

```
словарь = {
'значение1': 0,
'значение2': 0
}
```

2.Есть папка с текстовыми файлами.

В словарь записаны нужные мне ключи присутствующие в файлах. Мне нужно найти ключи из словаря в файлах, каждый раз когда ключ находится к значению ключа добавить единицу.
Не понимаю как реализовать код. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Пример что у вас должно получится и пример текста. Из текста достаются все значения или выборочно?

Comment: структуру файла бы еще

Answer (score 0):

Уверен, что есть вариант на много проще двух циклов, но это первое, что пришло в голову.

```
test_dict = {'word1': 0, 'word2': 0}

def check_file(file, dict):
    with open(file) as my_file:
        for word in my_file.read().split():
            for key, val in dict.items():
                if word == key:
                    dict[key] += 1
    return test_dict

print(check_file('file.txt', test_dict))
```

Comment: допустим  есть слово  '"word1"' в тексте. Как быть?

Comment: Как  я понял это и нужно автору, считать слова (которые задаются ключами в словаре) в тексте

Comment: Допустим my_file.read() = 'word1: 98765\n' или  '\n"word1" 98775\n"? ведь ваш алгоритм 'word1' не найдет.